# How to install and use network attached printer in CentOS 7

Tags: printing, centos-7

I have a printer on my local network that I can add to CentOS, but print jobs just spool forever, stuck in 'processing'. Not even the test page will print. Initially I had to disable the firewall and selinux before the printer was even detectable for adding. When first added it printed a test page. After this I can now remove and add the printer automatically, it can be found on the network with all the security enabled, but still nothing will print.

How do I resolve this?

Further information:

- Printer is Kyocera ECOSYS M6026cdn, and I have the driver downloaded and installed for it from the kyocera website.
- CUPS us running and `http://127.0.0.1:631` accesses the web interface same as the settings menu does, but still nothing will print.
- In Windows, the printer location is listed as `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5358/DeviceService/`. When using this address in CentOS, the error is "The printer is unreachable at this time.".
- In CentOS, the connection is detected as `dnssd://Kyocera%20ECOSYS%20M6026cdn._ipp._tcp.local/`. When using this address, the error is "Unable to find printer".

Further information #2:

- The Windows address was to the IP address of the Windows machine, which presumably addressed some internal port to access the actual printer. I can see that the printer URI format is specific to the printer model, but cannot find the format for this printer.
- I believe, by digging into the router's DHCP, that I have the printer's IP address, but without the URI format, cannot use it. I can however ping the address.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the printer found by CUPS and alter the machine address to `socket://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, and am now able to print both the test pages and from applications.
The method required stopping the `cups` daemon, editing the configuration file, and restarting the daemon

```
  > systemctl stop cups
  > vi /etc/cups/printers.conf
    ... 'i' to enter text editing
    ... Edit location string
    ... 'Esc + :wq' to save and close
  > systemctl start cups
```